# How to change the output of custom posts from the category on the tags?

Tags: php, wordpress

I found a similar record output function for custom posts:
(in functions.php)

```
function get_related_posts( $taxonomy = '', $args = array() ){
/*
 * Before we do anything and waste unnecessary time and resources, first check if we are on a single post page
 * If not, bail early and return false
 */
if ( !is_single() )
    return false;

/*
 * Check if we have a valid taxonomy and also if the taxonomy exists to avoid bugs further down.
 * Return false if taxonomy is invalid or does not exist
 */
if ( !$taxonomy ) 
    return false;

$taxonomy = filter_var( $taxonomy, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING );
if ( !taxonomy_exists( $taxonomy ) )
    return false;

/*
 * We have made it to here, so we should start getting our stuff togther. 
 * Get the current post object to start of
 */
$current_post = get_queried_object();

/*
 * Get the post terms, just the ids
 */
$terms = wp_get_post_terms( $current_post->ID, $taxonomy, array( 'fields' => 'ids') );

/*
 * Lets only continue if we actually have post terms and if we don't have an WP_Error object. If not, return false
 */
if ( !$terms || is_wp_error( $terms ) )
    return false;

/*
 * Set the default query arguments
 */
$defaults = array(
    'post_type' => $current_post->post_type,
    'post__not_in' => array( $current_post->ID),
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => $taxonomy,
            'terms' => $terms,
            'include_children' => false
        ),
    ),
);

/*
 * Validate and merge the defaults with the user passed arguments
 */
if ( is_array( $args ) ) {
    $args = wp_parse_args( $args, $defaults );
} else {
    $args = $defaults;
}

/*
 * Now we can query our related posts and return them
 */
$q = get_posts( $args );

    return $q;
}
```

In my template single-color, I'm calling my function

```
<div class="similar">
<h2 class="similar-h2">colors</h2>
<?php 
if ( function_exists( 'get_related_posts' ) ) {
    $related_posts = get_related_posts( 'colors_tax', array( 'posts_per_page' => 5,  'orderby' => 'rand') );
    if ( $related_posts ) {
        foreach ( $related_posts as $post ) {
            setup_postdata( $post ); 
?>
    <div class="sim-col1">
        <figure class="i-bot-similar">                    
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" rel="nofollow"> 
                <?php the_post_thumbnail(array(244,244,true)); ?>
            </a>            
        </figure>
        <h3 class="no-m"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" rel="nofollow"> <?php the_title();?></a></h3>
        <strong class="sim-strong"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" rel="nofollow"> <?php echo $ncolors; ?></a></strong>
    </div>
<?php
        }
        wp_reset_postdata();
    }
}
?>
```

It's work for category. How to change the output of custom posts from the category on the tags?

Comment: As this is evidently my code, ;-) I will try to answer it. I'm just a bit unclear what you want, do you need to show tags instead of your custom taxonomy.

Comment: Thanks! Once again, you are helping me))) Yes, I want show similar post for my custom posts type by tags. (http://prntscr.com/7mp2et )

Comment: The post type is automatically set to the post type of the single post, so you should get posts from the particular post type. As for tags, if they are the default build in tag system, you can pass `post_tag` to the taxonomy parameter in the function